# How to recreate a activity with last used fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, recreate

I have a fragment say FRAG A in my activity, now i have added one more fragment on top of it say FRAG B. Now i want to recreate the activity with FRAG A and FRAG B. But the fragments should go through the config changes means it should reload or recreate.

Comment: elaborate with an example if you can...

Comment: explain something more

Comment: please tell why you want to recreate ?
do you want to stop activity to recreate when orientation is changed ?

Comment: I am supporting multiple languages in my app. If a person changes the language whole app should be updated with new language and this includes all the api call i already made. So recreating the activity which will help me pull the data from server in the new language as well changes the local strings.

Answer (score 0):

Just have save a boolean in shared preference. If boolean is false reload Frag A and if its true reload Frag B. Depending on where the user left off use can store Shared preference. I am assuming that you want to recreate last seen fragment on app closed and then opened.